# How do you use move-resourcepool?

Tags: powercli

I run:

Move-ResourcePool -ResourcePool testresource -Destination myhost.mydomain.com

And get:

Move-ResourcePool : Cannot bind parameter 'Destination' to the target.
    Exception setting "Destination": "Unable to cast object of type         VMware.VimAutomation.ViCore.Util10.Surrogate.DefaultValue.StringWrapperResourcePool' to type 'VMware.VimAutomation.ViCore.Interop.V1.Inventory.VIContainerInterop'."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it breaks trying to translate your `-Destination` string into an object. Curious if this works any better?

```
Move-ResourcePool -ResourcePool testresource -Destination (Get-VMHost myhost.mydomain.com)
```